# Where to find the correct jsp file in a server with LifeRay

Tags: jsp, liferay, redhat

I'm new to jsp and need to change some html values within a jsp file. I'm unable to find out which jsp files I need to change as there are several files with the same name scattered throughout the system. I'm using RedHat Enterprise Server 6.2. The CMS we used is Liferay. There is a separate server for Liferay, Jboss, Database and LDAP.

Where are the jsp files for the life site stored? And do I need to create and deploy a new war file after making any changes?

Comment: You can download portal source code and search for the respective jsp which can then be changed using a Hook plugin.Hope that should serve your purpose.

Comment: Commenting here after your comment to my answer: Your question is by far not complete enough. "Where do I find *the correct JSP*?" Counterquestions: "For doing *what*?". And no, you *don't* just change random JSPs if you *don't* want to create an unmaintainable mess with random changes. That's what Liferay's plugin mechanism is for. I'm assuming you're using Liferay 6.2

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand you and I'll try to answer.

Your portlet (and it's called portlet since you are using Liferay) use that jsp which path is mentioned in your portlet.xml file. For example:

```
<init-param>
     <name>view-template</name>
     <value>/html/mygreeting/view.jsp</value>
</init-param>
```

In my situation Im using jsp in the html folder. You can use as many jsp as you want, but you should initialize it correctly.

And about your second question - no, you don't need to do it, Liferay has autodeploy.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds suspiciously like a wrong understanding of Liferay. The live content is in a database. Jsps  make up how this content is rendered by portlets and it depends which portlet renders content. You sound like you want to change content - which you'd edit through the cms UI. Changing jsps is possible but considered a customization of the platform and a developer task. If you want to change the overall appearance, you deploy a theme. The mechanics of customization vary depending on the version.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on the question. From my limited understanding, there are several custom forms in jsp being created which are linked to the Liferay CMS. I did see several jsp files with the html section that corresponds exactly to those forms. Since there are several similar forms in different locations, I'm unsure which one is used in the live site. I tried changing the files with different modifications so that I could see which one is being used. However none of the changes are reflected in the site. Do I need to restart tomcat/jboss for the changes to be reflected?